# How to declare a nested reactive component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reactive-programming

When reading ["Reactivity in Depth"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) in the documentation, I see two points which I am not sure how to interpret:

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data
> option, Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them
> to getter/setters using `Object.defineProperty`

(...)

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of
> `Object.observe`), Vue **cannot detect property addition or
> deletion**. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process
> during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data
> object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

How does this related to nested object such as

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
      {
        "c": 1
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 10,
    "b": [
      {
        "c": 10
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

**Specifically, how should such object be presented to `data()` so that it is reactive?**

```
data() {
    return {
        likeThis: [],
        orLikeThat: [{}],
        orMoreDetailed: [{a: null, b:[]}],
        orTheFullStucture: [{a: null, b:[{c: null}]}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are misunderstanding the [property addition/deletion caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). The statement in the first section of the docs that you reference holds true for your example object. If you set that object as a property of the object returned by the `data` method, everything within that object will be reactive.

Here's a simple example where I've set your object as `myNestedData` in the `data` method. I've bound `myNestedData[0].b[0].c` via `v-model` to an input element and you can see that changes to that value are reflected in the `myNestedData` object itself.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myNestedData: [{
        "a": 1,
        "b": [{ 
          "c": 1
        }]
      }, {
        "a": 10,
        "b": [{
          "c": 10
        }]
      }]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="myNestedData[0].b[0].c" type="number">
  <br>
  {{ myNestedData }}
</div>
```

---

Any of the examples you gave in your final section of code would be fully reactive, as in my example above. The property addition/deletion caveat only comes into play if you attempt to add or remove properties from those reactive data objects.

Here's a simple example where a `foo` property is initially set in the `data` method with a value of `[{ a: 'apple' }]`. Then `this.foo[0].b` is set to `'banana'` in the `created` hook of the component. But, because the `b` property of `this.foo[0]` didn't exist before, that property is not reactive. You can see this by changing the value of the second input, which is bound to via `v-model` to `foo[0].b`. Changing that value does not update the value that property in `foo`.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      foo: [{ a: 'apple' }]
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.foo[0].b = 'banana';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="foo[0].a">
  <input v-model="foo[0].b">
  <br>
  {{ foo }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The point which is still not clear is what can and cannot be added. In your example you add a non-reactive `this.foo[0].b`. But if `foo` was initialized as `[]`, would such addition be possible? (because whatever is added to the list will obviously be an 'insertion', without knowledge of what is being inserted)

Comment: Anything can be added but adding a property to an object that has already been declared won't be reactive. [See the docs on the change detection caveats.](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) In my example, if foo was initialized as `[]` I could push an object `{ b: 'banana' }` to the array and then `this.foo[0].b` would be reactive because I did not add a new property to any existing object in that process.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I got it. This is specifically a **property** added to an **object** which will not be reactive. Thanks a lot for clarifying that.